# UIFIleSharing populating UIPickerView

Tags: arrays, uipickerview

I'm new to the site and probably even newer to app development, however i'm learning slowly.. lol

So i hit my first big snag, I've researched all over on the web and can't find what I'm looking for, so here we go.

I'm creating an app that calls upon some user inputted files that can and do change on occasion.  I've added the `UIFileSharing` option for this so users can upload files via iTunes.

There are 3 different types of files that will need to be used, `a .opt, a .pkg, and a .txt`.

Is there some way i can take the files from the directory, read them, and based off the file extension pull them and use them in a `UIPickerView` wheel?  I'm really new at this so please forgive me when i ask you to be specific.

My assumption is to do this in a few steps, first read the files and sort them and place them in an array based on the extension, then use said array to populate the picker, and also to get the count for number of rows etc..

I guess the second two parts are pretty simple to figure out, just setting up a picker to use an array, i just need to know if its possible to build that array based on the user loaded files.

thanks in advance,

Chuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it guys, thanks for all the help.. Code is below, for anyone interested.  Don't forget to define your arrays!

```
NSArray *paths =  NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSArray *bundleDirectory = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsPath error:nil];

NSPredicate *Option = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.opt'"];
_OptionArray = [bundleDirectory filteredArrayUsingPredicate:Option];

_OptionPickerData = [_OptionArray copy];
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the `UIDocumentInteractionController` class.

Simple Example

```
 UIDocumentInteractionController * controller;
NSURL *fileURL=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[self getFilePath]]
controller = [ UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: fileURL ];
```

// How to get File From the Document Directory

```
-(NSString *)getFilePath{
    NSString *documentPath= [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Your file name"]
}
```

Comment: Did i mention i'm really new to this? lol..  i guess what i'm looking to do is create a NSMutableArray based on the contents of the folder, what i've got so far is:    for (NSString *file in files) {
        if ([file.pathExtension compare:@"opt" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame) {
            NSString *fullPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
            [retval addObject:fullPath];    I don't need to read the files or anything, just list them and be able to choose them from the picker wheel.